# Toggle text within a variable type function in React JS

Tags: reactjs, text, toggle

Let's say I have a function:

```
import React from "react";

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

I want to toggle the Hello World text on and off with a button. How would I achieve this? I have looked at:

1. [How React.js Toggle Button Works](https://medium.com/path2code/how-react-js-toggle-button-works-99c838ae2fe1)
2. [React js onclick toggle class in map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299805/react-js-onclick-toggle-class-in-map-function)

And none of them helped really. They used `this.state`, to which I got a type error, and then I started wondering if I should use a variable type function or not, as all the tutorials I've looked at use `class` instead. So my question is, how would I achieve toggling text in a variable type function?

If you need anymore information, or if my question was poorly phrased, please tell me. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state` has no meaning in your functional component.

Instead you could do something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {showText && <h1>Hello World</h1>}
      <button onClick={() => setShowText(!showText)}>Toggle</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

We use `useState` to create some state and set its initial value to `false` (i.e. The text should not be shown).

Then inside the `onClick` property of our button we can toggle the state value between `true` and `false` by setting `showText` and use this to conditionally render the text.

[sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-sea-sopf0?file=/src/App.js:0-302)

Comment: Great! That works, thank you so much Bas! One more thing though, if I have another paragraph, (like [this](https://pastecode.io/s/mjJiEDv251)), the Hello World text is on top of the "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" text (obviously). But is there a way that the hello world text could be beside that paragraph instead of on top?

Comment: Do you mean you want the `h1`on the left and the `p` on the right visually?

Comment: And another thing (sorry hehe), when I refresh the page, that Hello World text is gone and I have to toggle it again. How could I make it stay?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I mean :D

Comment: For the styling part you could render a `div` which has an `h1` and a `p` tag inside of it. Then you could use flexbox to put the `h1` and `p` next to eachother by letting these styles apply on the div: `display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'`. You could put spacing on the items as needed. As far as the refresh problem goes, React doesn't persist data across refreshes. You could use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to do this for example, but I think that would fit better as a separate question if you don't figure it out.

Comment: ...Or use localStorage if you don't want the data to be cleared when the page session ends.

Comment: Okay thank you Bas! I'm fairly new to React and have finished some courses on it, but I'll try this. Thank you again!

Comment: @Snowi No problem, glad to help. Btw in addition to accepting answers you can also upvote answers that you find helpful, as you've surpassed the threshold of 15 reputation.

Comment: Oh, I can do that now? Thanks Bas!

Answer (score 0):

**Toggle the Paragraph text on and off with a button, solved it-**

***Easily Solve it:***

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';


function App() {
 const [showParagraph, setShowParagraph]=useState(false)
 console.log('App RUNNING');
 const toggleParagrapher = () => {
    setShowParagraph((prevparagraph)=> !prevparagraph)
 }

  return (
    
    <div >
      <h1>Hi</h1>
      {showParagraph && <p>Hello Word</p> }
      <Button onClick={toggleParagrapher} variant="contained" color="success">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```