# How to save toggled tag to local storage in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483097/toggle-text-within-a-variable-type-function-in-react-js), after I got the toggle working, I asked if there was a way I could keep it there, to which the person who answered my question told me to use local storage.

> As far as the refresh problem goes, React doesn't persist data across
> refreshes. You could use sessionStorage to do this for example, but I
> think that would fit better as a separate question if you don't figure
> it out.
>
> ...Or use localStorage if you don't want the data to be cleared when
> the page session ends.

Then I started researching about local storage and how to use it in React JS. I tried coding it myself, but it ended up being very complicated and my code was so messy.

The thing is, that question also had to do with my money tracker app. Basically, the text being toggled was instead a **tag** being toggled.

[image: Image of the app]

Here are some parts of the money tracker app's documentation that I wrote in my [docs on novem.](https://nobyxi.github.io/novem-website/) website:

> 1. The first bar with the cyan plus sign is called the input bar. You add in something like $8.00 - Bought a shirt, and a output bar (the
>    bar with the 3 buttons on the right) is what you get with what you
>    entered in.

[image: Output bar]

A bit later...

> 1. The first one, the one with the cyan background, is the spent button. To put it simple, it toggles a tag with a cyan background that
>    says spent.
> 2. The second one, the button in the middle, is the earned button. It does the same thing as the spent button but instead of the words spent
>    it says earned.
> 3. The last one is the delete button that deletes the whole output bar.

**Note:** It might be better if you see the [website](https://nobyxi.github.io/novem-website/), because it is a very short page.

**React JS snippet of my code**

```
<div className="bar-tag-container">
        <li className={`todo-item ${todo.completed ? "completed" : ""}`}>
          {isSpent && <p className="tag">Spent</p>}
          {isReceived && <p className="tag">Earned</p>}
          <div className="others">{text}</div>
        </li>
      </div>

      <button
        onClick={(() => setIsSpent(!isSpent), handleClickSpent)}
        className="spent-btn"
      >
        <FaMoneyCheckAlt />
      </button>

      <button
        onClick={(() => setIsReceived(!isReceived), handleClickReceived)}
        className="receive-btn"
      >
        <FaDollarSign />
      </button>
```

Comment: how does your onClick handler for the cyan button looks like ? can you please share the code for it .

Comment: How do I do bounties? I would like solve this problem soon.

Comment: can you join in this room - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232932/issue-fix

Comment: No I can't. I don't have enough rep. And why?

Comment: Is your issue fixed ?

Comment: If you mean this question about saving the toggled tags, no, I have not solved it yet.

Comment: Hello...I still have the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code from you previous question.

To set `onClick` the value of your input you can do it in a function `handleClick` like so :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const handleClick = () => {
    setShowText(!showText)
    localStorage.setItem('myText', showText);
}


const Test = () => {
    const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {showText && <h1>Hello World</h1>}
            <button onClick={() => handleClick}>Toggle</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Comment: Hi crg, sorry for the late reply. In the toggle button, you're doing `onClick={() => handleClick`. But I still have the `() => setIsSpent(!isSpent)` part in there. How do I add both in? Thank you!

Comment: [Image](https://ibb.co/Ypvn7gL), [Full Code](https://pastecode.io/s/s9ba79epte), [Part of Todo.js](https://pastecode.io/s/zv9jhxm8j9). I think that's all the code needed. In the image, you can see the keys isReceived and isSpent - is the value meant to be like that? I don't understand it...please reply, thank you crg!